# DataFrame's as matrices in matrix product

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have the following two DataFrame's in Pandas.

```
import Pandas as pd

data1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'col3': [2,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I would like to treat the above 2 DataFrame as one $3\times 2$ matrix and one $2\times 1$ matrix and get the matrix product of data1*data2. I tried using

```
df = df1.dot(df2)
```

But I got an error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [244], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 vol_df.dot(weight_df['basket_weight'].T)

File /shared/mamba/micromamba/envs/xr-sw-2209/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1507, in DataFrame.dot(self, other)
   1505 common = self.columns.union(other.index)
   1506 if len(common) > len(self.columns) or len(common) > len(other.index):
-> 1507     raise ValueError("matrices are not aligned")
   1509 left = self.reindex(columns=common, copy=False)
   1510 right = other.reindex(index=common, copy=False)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indices are not aligned (you would need to have col1/col2 as **indices** of `df2`).

```
data1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'col3': [2,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['col1', 'col2'])

df1.dot(df2)

   col3
0    14
1    19
2    24
```

Or, manually align:

```
df1.dot(df2.set_axis(df1.columns))
```

Another option is to use the underlying numpy array to bypass alignment:

```
df1.dot(df2.to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
    0
0  14
1  19
2  24
```

If you want a multiplication:

```
df1.mul(df2['col3'], axis=1)

   col1  col2
0     2    12
1     4    15
2     6    18
```

Comment: Can you expand on "indices are not aligned"?

Comment: Sure, I added some details, let me know if this is enough. Like most pandas operations, an index/column alignment is performed before the operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. But df1 is size 3x2 and my df2 is size 2x1. That fits the definition for matrix multiplication perfectly. I do not see how my DataFrame's mismatch.

Comment: Because of the index/column names that are different. Draw your matrices on a paper to see for yourself, the names list match and `[0, 1]` doesn't match `['col1', 'col2']`. Did my solution(s) not work for you? Do you even want a dot product? Can you provide the exact expected output?

Comment: So you are saying for the matrix multiplication to work, not only the number of columns of df1 have to be equal to the number of rows of df2, but the column names of df1 also have to be the same as the row names of df2. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hans this is correct. Compare `pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}).dot(pd.DataFrame({'C': [5, 6]}))` and `pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}).dot(pd.DataFrame({'C': [5, 6]}, index=['A', 'B']))`

Comment: Internally, pandas explicitly compares the names with `common = self.columns.union(other.index)`, so if no common names there is nothing to work on.